# ipdb continue after hitting a bug

Tags: python, debugging

I use the ipdb debugger in the following way:

```
ipython --pdb bugged.py
```

on a file *bugged.py*:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
print(a[5])
a = 2 + a
print(a)
```

What happens then is that the debugger kicks in at the faulty line; this is the expected behavior:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jrlab/Desktop/Current/debug_ipython/bugged.py in <module>()
      2 
      3 a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
----> 4 print(a[5])
      5 a = 2 + a
      6 print(a)

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
> /home/jrlab/Desktop/Current/debug_ipython/bugged.py(4)<module>()
      2 
      3 a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
----> 4 print(a[5])
      5 a = 2 + a
      6 print(a)

ipdb> n
~/Desktop/Current/debug_ipython>
```

But what I would like really is to continue execution at the next instruction when I press **n** (or any other command), i.e. that I am able to continue running the script further once I fixed by hand with **!** commands the execution of the faulty line.

Is there any way to do that?

### Edits

1: I want this behavior in the case where the script takes a long time to run; I would like to be able to resume execution when I fixed a minor bug in the middle of the script, without the need to do a time consuming re-run from start.

2: I am aware of what this error is an I know how to fix it. The buggy code is shown only as a way to illustrate the behavior I want (i.e., resume code after the print(a[5]) if I want.

Comment: I think there may be a way to get this behavior, but not sure how. The idea is that one already gets this kind of behavior in IPython: you can have one line of code per cell, then when one cell crashes fix it, and continue again to run cells from under. Question is, how can we get something similar from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you get an error because the offending line trie to access the 6-th element of an array that contains only 3.

Normally, the Python Debugger allows to skip an offending line, unsure for ipython. But on my standard installation I could do:

```
j 5
n
```

The `j 5` sets the current line after the offending one and the `n` successfully executes it.

Comment: I am aware that this is the error, I am only taking it as a simple example ;) I make it clearer in the comment now.